# Tail or Head Recursion

Tags: recursion

`Is this a tail recursion?

```
def addOn(arr, i, j):
    if i<=j:
        arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i-1]
        return addOn(arr, i+1, j)
    return arr
```

`

I want to make a funtion that accepts an array and outputs an array that every element is the sum of current and previous element using tail recursive

Comment: Please provide example input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It's tail-recursive. There's two possible code paths for the function to exit -

```py
def addOn(arr, i, j):
    if i<=j:
        arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i-1]
        return addOn(arr, i+1, j) # exit
    return arr                    # exit
```

As with all tail-recursive functions, it can be converted to a `while` loop -

```py
def addOn(arr, i, j):
    while i <= j:                   # while..
        arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i-1]
        i = i+1                     # ..loop
    return arr                      # exit
```

Note Python does not eliminate stack frames for tail calls so overflows will still happen.